# Detect the directive property value change within the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have below mentioned custom directive for detecting the element's click event.

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDir', [
        '$document', function ($document) { 

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.IsWizardOpen = false;

                    element.on('click', function (e) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.IsWizardOpen = true;
                        });
                        e.stopPropagation(); //stop event from bubbling up to document object
                    });

                }
            };
        }]);
```

I have tried to watch the changes of the `IsWizardOpen`property inside the controller as shown below.But it's not working ? The value of `IsWizardOpen`has been changed when clicked the element (i.e. `true`).So can you tell me where's the issue ? Thanks in advance.

**Controller**

```
$scope.$watch('IsWizardOpen', function () {
            if ($scope.IsWizardOpen) {
                //my task
            }
        });
```

**Html**

```
<div my-dir>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `IsWizardOpen`? what you mean?

Comment: @RameshRajendran It's just a scope property which I need it to capture the `click` event.

Comment: It won't work, since it's a primitive it is bound to the child scope, and the controller's scope won't know of it.

Comment: @OmriAharon Yes.Can you tell me how to change it to work properly.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OmriAharon But I can access that value (`IsWizardOpen`) within the html page.

Comment: Working on a fiddle for you

Comment: why are you needing to watch in controller in the first place? this looks like an X-Y problem

Comment: @charlietfl B'cos if user clicks that element then It should open a popup screen.

Comment: @OmriAharon Ok thanks.Please let me know once you done it.

Comment: @charlietfl That popup screen needs not to be opened for hyper links.That is why I have used this.Other wise I can use `ng-click()`.

Comment: Use a service to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So primitive values are bound to child scopes when they're assigned, therefore you need to have an object wrapping it. For digging deeper, read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

I made a fiddle with some slight changes, basically I created a wrapper object in the controller and then your directive updates it:

**Controller:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.wrapper = {};

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.wrapper.IsWizardOpen;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                alert('watch works');
            }
        });
}
```

**Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('myDir', [
        '$document', function ($document) { 

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: true,
                template: '<div>Click Me!</div>',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                    scope.wrapper.IsWizardOpen = false;

                    element.on('click', function (e) {

                        scope.wrapper.IsWizardOpen = true;
                        scope.$apply();
                        e.stopPropagation(); //stop event from bubbling up to document object
                    });

                }
            };
        }]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/HB7LU/13129/)

Comment: Wow.. Great.Thanks a lot my friend.I have learned a lot today.Thanks again. :)